# Почему при вводе даты рождения в консоль выводится не возраст, а NaN

Tags: javascript, дата

```
  function createNewUser() {
   //     let userName = prompt("Enter your name");
   //     let userLastName = prompt("Enter your last name");
   //     let userDateBirth = new Date(prompt("Enter your date of birth, 'dd.mm.yyyy'"));

  //     const newUser = {
  //     firstName: userName,
  //     lastName: userLastName,
  //     birthday: userDateBirth.getFullYear(),
  //     getLogin() {
  //         return (this.firstName[0] + this.lastName).toLowerCase(); 
  //     } ,
  //     getAge() {
  //         let date = new Date();
  //         return (Number(date.getFullYear()) - Number(this.birthday));
  //     } ,
  //     getPassword() {
  //         return (this.firstName[0].toUpperCase() + this.lastName.toLowerCase() + 
          this.birthday);
   //     } ,
       // } 
  // return newUser
  // }

  // const user = createNewUser()

  // console.log(user.getLogin());
  // console.log(user.getAge());
  // console.log(user.getPassword());
```

Comment: Начнём с того, что выводиться ничего не может, потому что почти весь код зачем-то закомментирован

Comment: Но даже если всё раскомментировать, то при корректных входных данных возраст выводится без проблем и никаких NaN нету

Comment: @andreymal `нет`*, не понимаю почему у вас нет `NaN`'ов... У меня почему-то в lastName `NaN` (Я вводил `993`), плюс к тому, почему-то тс (Елена) пытается прибавить дату к строке (А до этого пытается перевести дату, которая строка, в тип числа, а дата к слову такая `dd.mm.yyyy`), поэтому выводится `NaN` в третьем логе. Поэтому как у вас `NaN` не выводится, я не понимаю.

Comment: @ΝNL993 мой chromium прекрасно обрабатывает дату в формате dd.mm.yyyy, правда, путает местами месяц и день (а вот firefox не может, да)